# How to rearrange numbers using SED (transposition)

Tags: sed

I have a line:

```
The ID number for product is 721- 971-4321.`
```

I want to swap the area code and exchange it for the number inside, like so: `971- 721-4321`

Here is what I have:

```
17s/\([654]\)-\([817]\)/\2-\1/
```

So the number is on line 17 in a .txt file. There is other stuff on the line but I want to only change the number.

Whenever I run the script nothing happens. Any advice how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]*\)\([^-]*\)\([^0-9]*\)\([^-]*\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\2\5/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** I am using here back reference capability of `sed` here. Where by using regex I am creating 5 temporary buffers and then accessing them in reorder to make output as per OP's request.

Output will be as follows.

```
The ID number for product is 971- 721-4321.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+-) ([0-9]+-)/\2 \1/' file
```